# cannot start mysql server bind socket denied

Tags: linux, mysql, sockets

I have been trying to start mysql server but got this error:

```
Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Operation not permitted
2013-10-21 13:53:54 25098 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: [my-home-dir]/mysql-server/mysql.socket ?
```

I have searched all pages on google on this topic and have tried all methods, but have no luck.

So here are some more details. I do not have root access on the computer. What I do is install mysql server on my local directory. My my.cnf file looks like this:

```
[mysqld]
 basedir = ~/mysql ## mysql unzipped files
 datadir = ~/mysql-server/data
 port = 3666
 socket = ~/mysql-server/mysql.socket
 user = my-ubuntu-user-name
```

My installation steps are:

1. Unzip the source code distribution of mysql 5.6 to ~/mysql
2. Create my.cnf as I showed above.
3. Initialize the server. This step does not show error.

   ```
   ./scripts/mysql_install_db --defaults-file=my.cnf --user=my-ubuntu-user --datadir=~/mysql-server/data --basedir=~/mysql --socket=~/mysql-server/mysql.socket
   ```
4. Start the server

   ```
   ./bin/mysqld --defaults-file=my.cnf
   ```

   And hence comes the error:

   ```
   Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Operation not permitted
   2013-10-21 13:53:54 25098 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: [my-home-dir]/mysql-server/mysql.socket ?
   ```

Also, I have 755 access on all folders related. Any suggestions would be helpful!

---Update

1. netstat gives no processes on 3666 running.
2. no process called mysql is currently running.

Comment: do you get any output from `netstat -tlup | grep 3666`

Comment: Is mysql running? `ps -ef|grep mysql|grep -v grep` will tell you. 755 won't let you write if you're not the owner. Check who is the owner of `~/mysql-server/` with `ls -ld ~/mysql-server/` and `ls -ld ~/mysql-server/mysql.socket`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you look at the file at /etc/my.cnf and see whether a property like `basedir=/var/lib` is there under `[mysql.server]`?

If it is there, then try to comment out that property and starting mysql again.